# How to display values with NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to display the value of an object with NSManagedObjectContext but I don't know what I should do with this code. Should I use a NSManagedModel or something else?

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {

        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }

    return context;
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
         [super viewDidLoad];

     NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Match"];

      self.playersArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy

     //What should I do here?

      UILabel *locationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 1000, 20)];
     [locationLabel setText: //trying to get this];
     [self.view addSubview:locationLabel];

}
```

I am a beginner at xcode and don't know much about core data. Any help is appreciated.

I want to do something like this:

```
 NSManagedObjectModel *playerModel = [self.playersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

and then do:

```
[playerModel valueForKey: @"location"];
```

but I want my data to be displayed in a view controller not a tableview controller.

Comment: What is `locationLabel` supposed to display? Does it have to do with  `playersArray`?

Comment: I declared an attribute called "location" in my xcdatamodeid. playersArray is supposed to contain "location". I just want to display it

Comment: see my answer below and lemme know if that helps

Comment: It's very, very unusual for there to be any reason to use `NSManagedModel` in code anywhere except for when you're setting up Core Data when your app launches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to display the location of the first player in the array and that the location is stored as a string, you would do this:

```
....
 self.playersArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy

NSManagedObjectModel *playerModel = [self.playersArray objectAtIndex:0]

  UILabel *locationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 1000, 20)];
 [locationLabel setText:playerModel.location];
 [self.view addSubview:locationLabel];
....
```

Comment: sry this didn't work :( I am trying to do something like this     NSManagedObjectModel *playerModel = [self.playersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], but i don't want my data to be in a tableview. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user4567987 see my edit and lemme know if that's what you mean